# Undefined variable "myTiff2mat1" or class "myTiff2mat1.img"

Tags: matlab

I am struggling with this problem since 2 days. Please help me out on this. I am working on vessel branch segmentation and i have got the code from mathworks central.

http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36031-vessel-branch-segmentation

Please download the submission from that site, and open the readme.txt

Now, in the Readme.txt of that I was asked to convert the tiff images to .mat format and I used the following code to convert it.

```
A = imread('C:\Users\123\Desktop\vbs\images\01_test.tif');
save('myTiff2mat1','A');
```

Now, when I tried to upload the .mat file using the UI window got after executing vesselbranchsegmentation.m

I am getting the following error

```
------------------------------
Undefined variable "myTiff2mat1" or class "myTiff2mat1.img".

Error in VesselBranchSegmentation>LoadMatFile (line 855)
eval(['img=' sprintf('%s',fileName(1:end-4)) '.img;']);

Error in VesselBranchSegmentation>ReadOrgImg (line 834)
    [img fileprefix]=LoadMatFile(pathName,fileName);

Error in VesselBranchSegmentation/CBMfileNew (line 120)
    [tmporgImg  saveFileName] = ReadOrgImg('Pick a mat file.');
Error while evaluating uimenu Callback
----------------------------------------------
```

Please help me a way out of this problem.

Comment: `imwrite`, goes nicely with `imread`

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `LoadMatFile()` it expects the .mat file to contain a variable with the same name as the file, so it looks for `myTiff2mat1` and ignores `A`.

Secondly, that still probably won't work because the README says to use `VBSreadTiff()` and you've used `imread()` which isn't going to create the correct data structure.

I don't have Matlab here to check it, but this *might* suffice as a hack:

```
myTiff2mat1.img = imread('C:\Users\123\Desktop\vbs\images\01_test.tif');
save('myTiff2mat1','myTiff2mat1');
```

Comment: there shouldn't be .img after the variable.

Comment: @NKN according to the structure `VBSreadTiff()` creates and the `eval` in `LoadMatFile()`; yes there should.

Comment: Thank you. Its working wonders. This is new error coming up. Help me out.   Elapsed time is 0.987052 seconds.
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in VBSvesselMask (line 20)
meanImg=mean(single(orgImg(:,:,windowSize+1:30)),  3);

Error in VesselBranchSegmentation/CBestimateVesselMask (line 294)
        [appImg masks(1).img]= VBSvesselMask(orgImg);
 
Error while evaluating uimenu Callback